# how do I generate random timestamps in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I need to generate a bunch of random times in Excel 2013.

The time needs to be between 7AM to 8:45AM

The number of rows varies but they are typically between 30 to 60

Comment: Specifically using VBA, or just in a cell using a formula?

Comment: There are several ways you can do this - but the method used may depend on what sort of time value you want, should they be whole seconds, whole minutes, every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 7):

Using a formula in a cell (for times ranging from 7:00:00AM to 8:44:59AM):

```
=TIME(7,RANDBETWEEN(0,104),RANDBETWEEN(0,59))
```

[image]

Comment: So I guess the 104 comes from adding 44 minutes to 60 minutes which will push the hour to 8 randomly. Hope this helps others quickly figure this out.

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress: Correct. You can supply a minute that exceeds 60, just like you can supply a month/day larger than 12/31 within the `DATE(year,month,day)` function, and Excel will automatically roll it over to the next highest unit of measure. For example, `DATE(2020,13,32)` yields 2021/02/01 (February 1st, 2021); 13th month is the first month (January) of the following year (2021) and 32nd day of the first month (January) is the first day of the following month (February in this case). The same goes for `TIME(hour,minute,second)`.

Answer (score 6):

In Excel, one day = 1

7AM = 7/24
845AM = 8.75/24

Enter the formula:

```
=7/24+RAND()*(8.75/24-7/24)
```

On the Home tab of the Ribbon, select 'Time' from the dropdown in the Number area.

This will generate a random time starting at 7am and continuing through 845am.

Comment: PS - RAND() and is among the 'volatile' formulas that will change each time the sheet recalculates. Copy and paste as values if you don't want the data to change constantly.

Comment: Please change it to: =7/24+RND()*(8.75/24-7/24)

Answer (score 0):

Fill the cells with:

=RAND()*(0.364583-0.291667)+0.291667

Answer (score 0):

you want to generate random time between two given times, such as generate time from 6 o'clock to 9 o'clock, you can use below formula. Type this formula: =TEXT(RAND()*(8:45-7)/24+6/24,"HH:MM:SS") into a blank cell, and drag the fill handle over to the range that you want to insert the time.